# Unauthorized with guzzlehttp/client

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, unauthorized

I have 2 services: Personal and Consumer
Personal service have 2 APIs:
- login(credentials) return an access token. 
- getUser() return user information with above access token inside headers 'Authorization'
Consumer service have 1 API:
- check(): use GuzzleHttp client call to Personal service.getUser() to get user, as follow:

```
            $response = $this->client->request('GET', 'http:localhost/personal/userinfo', [
               'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => $accessToken,
                ]
            ]);
```

When I use Postman to call 'http:localhost/personal/userinfo' directly, there's no error.
But when I call 'http:localhost/consumer/check', I catch error 401 - unauthorized

2 Services use [Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7), Personal use [Tymon/JWTAuth 1.0.0](https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth), Consumer service use [GuzzleHttp 6.5.4](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle)

Someone please help me to resolve this error. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you add `Bearer` as part of the Authorization header? For JWT I am pretty sure you need `Authorization: Bearer $accessToken`

Comment: Yes, I added "Bearer " prefix before accessToken.